# Chrome Javascript Debugger incorrectly traces errors to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, console

I'm using JQuery in one of my projects, and Chrome's debugging console is incorrectly tracing all errors to JQuery, citing line 16 in jquery-1.5.1.min.js every time. Firefox correctly traces errors to offending code, but sometimes Chrome encounters errors that Firefox does not, and it is extremely hard to find what is broken in these instances, as I'm dealing with 5 different scripts and 3000 lines of code.

Comment: "Incorrectly tracing all errors". You mean there should be **errors** that should be ignored ?

Comment: @DidierG. He means that the debugger is blaming all errors on a line in the jquery js instead of giving him the line number of his own code which is in fact the problem.

Comment: Don't blame Chrome. The fact that the errors are pointing to the jQuery source could be an indication that your code is wrongly implementing a jQuery method. Replace the minified jQuery file with the uncompressed jQuery file. Also, check the dependencies of your code: Do these snippets interfere with each other? Do they require a specific jQuery version? *Link to uncompressed file: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js*

Comment: Do you see a little dropdown arrow on the left? Try toggling the expando that that hides and see if it gives a stacktrace on the right, with the line number of your file on the right. I think that the ~250,000 javascript developers on this site would've caught such an error with Chrome and jQuery long before your first post today.

Comment: I've finally got back to to working on this, and here one such error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: fname is not defined", from jquery 1.7.1 line 7587, which is: "throw e;", in try and catch statement. Firefox however traces this error to the correct line in my script.